# how do i get out of this Infinite loop

Tags: while-loop, infinite-loop

I am trying to get this loop to ask the question again what the user inputs not a 1 or a 2 but it puts me in a infinite loop how do i get out?

```java
package vga;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FPS_Info {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean placeHolder;
        String gameList[] = new String[2];
        gameList[0] = ("Battlefield 1");
        gameList[1] = ("Call Of Duty WWII");
        System.out.printf("Please slect from theses games %s or %s.%nType 1 for %s and type 2 for %s.%n", 
                            gameList[0], gameList[1], gameList[0], gameList[1]);
        int gameSelection = scanner.nextInt();
        if (gameSelection == 1 || gameSelection ==2) {
            placeHolder = true;
        }
        while (placeHolder = true) {
        if (gameSelection == 1) {
            System.out.println("Battlefield 1, good choice.");
            break;
            } else if (gameSelection == 2) {
            System.out.println("Call Of Duty WWII, good selection.");
            break;
            } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter one of the options."); 
            placeHolder = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer pointing out the issue with `while (placeHolder = true)`, but I'm not 100% sure on what logic you were trying to implement.  It could help if you explained what you'd like the code to do in a bit more detail.

Comment: Language tag please

Comment: You have a major typo, assigning to the loop variable instead of checking for equality.

Answer (score 0):

If you restructure your code, you don't need the placeholder.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FPS_Info {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean placeHolder;
        String gameList[] = new String[2];
        gameList[0] = ("Battlefield 1");
        gameList[1] = ("Call Of Duty WWII");
        System.out.printf("Please slect from theses games %s or %s.%nType 1 for %s and type 2 for %s.%n",
                gameList[0], gameList[1], gameList[0], gameList[1]);

        int gameSelection = scanner.nextInt();
        while (gameSelection != 1 && gameSelection != 2) { // or while (gameSelection > 0 && gameSelection <= gameList.length)
            System.out.println("Please enter one of the options.");
            gameSelection = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        if (gameSelection == 1) {
                System.out.println("Battlefield 1, good choice.");
        }
        else if (gameSelection == 2) {
            System.out.println("Call Of Duty WWII, good selection.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code includes:

```
while (placeHolder = true)
```

You probably meant `placeHolder == true`.  The `=` assigns `true` rather than checks against it, so it's not doing the loop like you probably meant.

That said, there's no reason to `== true` in the first place.  You can just

```
while (placeHolder)
```